# Name of book about colony cut off from earth/passage blocked?

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization, wormhole

I vaguely recall that the book or series of books was about a human colony that had been cut off from the rest of humanity. I believe the passageway was blocked off in the first book and in the second this colony is found. I think I recall that the colony suffered from Xenophobia. Perhaps the passageway was a wormhole? I do not recall that well.

Does anyone have any idea what book/series that may be? I was interested in buying it once but then forgot where I found it and the title.

Comment: This is something of a common trope in Science Fiction. Can you fill in any more details? When you read it and whether it was new at the time, perhaps?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LostColony

Comment: Since you capitalized Xenophobia, was that some sort of specific condition or disease? Or was it just normal xenophobia?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Algebraist?

Comment: Or Lois McMaster Bujold's Vorkosigan series?

Comment: Antares Dawn by Michael McCollum?

Comment: Antares Dawn seems to fit quite nicely.  The second and third books are Antares Passage and Antares Victory.